# How to select a parent category and show the children to choose in another select?

Tags: categories

How to select a parent category and show the children to choose in another select?

this is the code (parent taxonomy)

```
<select>
<option value=""><?php esc_html_e('Selecciona País', 'eltd-tours'); ?></option>
        <?php 
            //Listado de taxonomias por país
            $tax_terms = get_terms(array(
            'taxonomy' => 'tipo_pais',
            'hide_empty' => false,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'orderby'    => 'parent',
            'fields' => 'all',
            'parent' => '0',                    ) );
            foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {?>
            <option value=""><?php echo $tax_term->name;?></option>
        <?php }?>

</select>
```

i need taxonomy child code, help please!

Comment: you mean you need to parent category wise  subcategory  display right?
otherwise  you need to the hierarchy of categories ?  please  give me answer   I  have  help  for  you

Comment: exact. I need to select the parent category, in a second select for example: `<select>
<option> taxonomy child 1 </option>
<option> taxonomy child 2 </option>
<option> taxonomy child 3 </option>
</select>
`
the options can be obtained dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

If I understoon you correctly, you want to have two `select`s, one for parent terms and the other for child terms, which will be dynamically populated based on the parent selection. Right?

First you need the html markup for the `select` elements.

```
<select name="parent_term">
  <option value=""><?php esc_html_e('Selecciona País', 'eltd-tours'); ?></option>
  <?php echo implode( '', my_select_options( my_parent_tax_terms('tipo_pais') ) ); ?>
</select>

<select name="child_term"></select>
```

Here's the helper functions I've used to make the html a little cleaner looking.

```
function my_parent_tax_terms( string $taxonomy ) {
  $terms = get_terms(array(
    'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
    'hide_empty'   => false,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'orderby'      => 'parent',
    'fields'       => 'all',
    'parent'       => '0',
  ) );
  return ( $terms && is_array($terms) ) ? $terms: array();
}

function my_select_options( array $terms ) {
  $out = array();
  foreach ($terms => $term) {
    $out[] = sprintf(
      '<option value="%d">%s</option>',
      $term->term_id,
      $term->name
    );
  }
  return $out;
}
```

Then add an event listener to the parent term `select` have it populate the child term `select` when the parent selection changes. You can do this with jQuery or plain javascript.

```
jQuery(document).on('ready', function(){
  // populate child term select, when parent selection changes
  jQuery('select[name="parent_term"]').on('change', function(){
    // get child terms select element
    var $child_select = jQuery('select[name="child_term"]');
    // clear any previous options
    jQuery($child_select).empty();
    // get new options
    var $child_options = get_child_terms_from_admin_ajax_or_WP_REST_or_localized_script();
    // loop options to append them to the child select
    for (i = 0; i < $child_options.length; i++) {
      jQuery($child_select).append(`<option value="${$child_options[i].value}">${$child_options[i].name}</option>`);
    }    
  });  
});
```

Note that the child terms need to come from somewhere. This could be either the legacy [admin-ajax](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins), the more modern [WP REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/), or you could even create a big config array with parent terms and their child terms and then make it available for jQuery/js with [wp_localize_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/).